# Can I return a different type from a function in a generic class depending on if the generic type used for the class is a value or a reference type?

Tags: c#, generics, return-type

I want to return a `Nullable<Value>` from a function in a generic class if Value is a value type, and just 'Value' if value is already a reference type.

I've been trying to work with where clauses to achieve this, but I can't seem to use a where class on a non-generic function, even in a generic class.

```cs
    public class HashTable<Key, Value>
    {
        private List<ValueSlot> valueSlots = new List<ValueSlot>();

        private struct ValueSlot
        {
            public bool hasValue;
            public List<KeyValuePair<Key, Value>> values;
        }

        //...

        public Nullable<Value> TryGetValue(Key key) where Value : struct
        {
            (bool result, Value value) = TryGetValue(valueSlots, key);

            if (result == true)
            {
                Nullable<Value> myVal = value;
                return myVal;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public Value TryGetValue(Key key) where Value : class
        {
            (bool result, Value value) = TryGetValue(valueSlots, key);

            return result == true ? value : (Value)null;
        }

        private (bool, Value) TryGetValue(List<ValueSlot> valueSlots, Key key)
        {
            //...
        }

        //...
    }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile an generates a bunch of errors.  I would rather not resort to returning tuples out from the class.  Is there a simple way to make this approach work that I am missing?  I've been trying to get this to work for nearly a week now...

Comment: Where's the third `TryGetValue` in your code? You've shown two, but you're calling a third. Also, what's `valueSlots`? You need a [mcve] for us to work with.

Comment: No, you can't overload a method based on return type and generic type constraints.

Comment: @Enigmativity The function isn't really relevant to the question.  It does some basic hashing and grabs a value, and it compiles.  I've added `valueSlots` to the snippet because that was a bit unclear and the empty function though.  It should now be clear what the inputs and outputs are.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, that's a bummer, but thanks for the prompt reply...

Comment: @Firestar9114 - It's amazing how many people think that something "isn't relevant". The rule is "if someone asks, then it's relevant".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymorphism by return type is not supported by C# yet. Generic type constraint is a hint to the compiler and not making method signatures different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Hopefully something like this gets added.  It would be really handy to have.

Comment: I wouldn't say a type constraint is "just a hint". It's not like the compiler can feel free to ignore it. Like the return type, it's not part of the method signature for overloading purposes, I agree - but "hint" has the wrong connotation IMO.

Comment: You are precisely correct @JonSkeet, that is not something you can avoid or consider "optional". Just could not find a better word to describe a relation between compiler and a language feature.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `Maybe<T>` so that you can do this:

```
public class HashTable<Key, Value>
{
    public Maybe<Value> TryGetValue(Key key)
    {
        (bool result, Value value) = TryGetValue(valueSlots, key);

        if (result == true)
        {
            return new Maybe<Value>(value); // or value.ToMaybe() // with the extension method
        }
        else
        {
            return Maybe<Value>.Nothing;
        }
    }
}
```

This works regardless of what type the `Value` is.

Here's the implementation that I use:

```
public static class MaybeEx
{
    public static Maybe<T> ToMaybe<T>(this T value)
    {
        return new Maybe<T>(value);
    }

    public static T GetValue<T>(this Maybe<T> m, T @default) => m.HasValue ? m.Value : @default;
    public static T GetValue<T>(this Maybe<T> m, Func<T> @default) => m.HasValue ? m.Value : @default();

    public static Maybe<U> Select<T, U>(this Maybe<T> m, Func<T, U> k)
    {
        return m.SelectMany(t => k(t).ToMaybe());
    }

    public static Maybe<U> SelectMany<T, U>(this Maybe<T> m, Func<T, Maybe<U>> k)
    {
        if (!m.HasValue)
        {
            return Maybe<U>.Nothing;
        }
        return k(m.Value);
    }

    public static Maybe<V> SelectMany<T, U, V>(this Maybe<T> @this, Func<T, Maybe<U>> k, Func<T, U, V> s)
    {
        return @this.SelectMany(x => k(x).SelectMany(y => s(x, y).ToMaybe()));
    }
}

public class Maybe<T>
{
    public class MissingValueException : Exception { }

    public readonly static Maybe<T> Nothing = new Maybe<T>();

    private T _value;
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!this.HasValue)
            {
                throw new MissingValueException();
            }
            return _value;
        }
        private set
        {
            _value = value;
        }
    }
    public bool HasValue { get; private set; }

    public Maybe()
    {
        HasValue = false;
    }

    public Maybe(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
        HasValue = true;
    }

    public T ValueOrDefault(T @default) => this.HasValue ? this.Value : @default;
    public T ValueOrDefault(Func<T> @default) => this.HasValue ? this.Value : @default();

    public static implicit operator Maybe<T>(T v)
    {
        return v.ToMaybe();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.HasValue ? this.Value.ToString() : "<null>";
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Maybe<T>)
            return Equals((Maybe<T>)obj);
        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(Maybe<T> obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(_value, obj._value)) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<bool>.Default.Equals(this.HasValue, obj.HasValue)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<T>.Default.GetHashCode(_value);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<bool>.Default.GetHashCode(this.HasValue);
        return hash;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Maybe<T> left, Maybe<T> right)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, null))
        {
            return object.ReferenceEquals(right, null);
        }

        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Maybe<T> left, Maybe<T> right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }
}
```

Comment: So `Maybe<T>` is basically a `Nullable<T>`, without the restriction of `T` being a non-nullable value type?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Yes, it's known as the "Maybe Monad". It's even more flexible as  `Maybe<string>.Nothing` is a **missing** string. `new Maybe<string>(null)` is a string that is `null`. And `new Maybe<string>("Hello")` is a string with a value of `"Hello"`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is a Maybe Monad. It requires some work. But it is worth it imho. Implementation for Maybe Monad for C# is well described [here](https://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2011/01/monads-in-c1-introduction.html?m=1&fbclid=IwAR1pHZiugQciEaz08lCKfdsrEYB0uuVRdATioAN8lnntI6X2WheckNe1bVA).

Comment: Especially if you've been working of this already for a week.

Comment: Please don't link to external sites unless it's supporting the content you've already put in your answer.

Comment: Was I not supporting my answer content with this link? O.o

Comment: No, you should have the content in your answer **and then link** to support that content.

Comment: It was not clear until I saw your answer. So you mean I should add code to my answer and only then would be allowed to add link?

Comment: No, I mean if there's anything on the page that you're linking to that you think answers this question then copy that content to your answer. You goal is to create an answer that would be sufficient on its own. Once you get there then you can add the link to support the content in your answer.

Comment: The term "sufficient on its own" is very subjective and depends of the education of the question author, which I can not estimate. Maybe he knew what Maybe Monad was and I just had to remind him... maybe even if I posted the entire contents of all those 7 articles that i linked to, he still would be able to understand what it is supposed to do. For example, I know, for sure, that my girlfriend wouldn't understand it even if I copy pasted all 7 articles here (and she is learning programming now). So what I see, is that it is merely your "perception" that I am not giving any content.

Comment: The content that I was from those articles was "Maybe Monad" the rest of the text in my articles are merely comments and personal opinion on the answer.

If I had posed the same question to my friends, they most likely would answer to me with exactly these 2 words (not more) "maybe monad" at which point I would have slapped may forehead and thanked for the answer. 

If my girlfriend had asked this question, proper answer would encompass days or, maybe even, weeks of explanation.

Comment: Seriously, you're being obstreperous. It's part of the role of all users on this site improve the quality of the questions and answers when they see something that could be improved. This answer needs improving.

Comment: You should consider that the users of this site are reasonably educated when it comes to coding (which I presume your girlfriend isn't). And you should assume that the reasonably educated coded has not ever heard of the Maybe monad and that your answer is their introduction.

Comment: So I guess the problem lies in the fact that I honestly do not know what is the definition of "reasonably educated" and you, apparently, "do".

Comment: Perhaps that's the difference between 134 rep points and 80,633?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195856/discussion-between-korulis-and-enigmativity).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some compromises to make this work:

```
public V? GetNullable<V>(Key key) where V : struct, Value
{
    (bool result, Value value) = TryGetValue(valueSlots, key);
    return result ? (V)value : (V?)null;
}

public V GetValueOrNull<V>(Key key) where V : class, Value
{
    (bool result, Value value) = TryGetValue(valueSlots, key);
    return result == true ? (V)value : null;
}
```

You must give different names to the two methods, and provide the type as parameter every time you call them:

```
var h1 = new HashTable<int, DateTime>(); // Value Type
DateTime? date = h1.GetNullable<DateTime>(1);

var h2 = new HashTable<int, Exception>(); // Reference Type
Exception ex = h2.GetValueOrNull<Exception>(1);
```

I guess that this defeats the purpose though.